# three.js HTML background as clearColor

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

I want to set the HTML background as clearColor in ***three.js***?

This is my ***three.js*** code:

```
// init
var vWebGL = new WEBGL();
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00fdf0 });
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;
renderer.clearColor(0x000000, 0.0);

// Render Loop
function animate() {
    renderer.setClearAlpha(0.0);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}


if (vWebGL.isWebGLAvailable()) {
    // Initiate function or other initializations here
    animate();
} else {
    var warning = vWebGL.getWebGLErrorMessage();
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(warning);
}
```

In My Webgl I can specify the HTML as clearColor.

```
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

My Webgl:

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `setClearColor()`? [**WebGLRenderer#setClearColor - three.js docs**](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setClearColor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background of a [`THREE.Scene`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene) can be set by setting the property [.background](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene.background):

e.g.

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xff0000); // red
```

If you want to have a transparent background, then the [`THREE.WebGLRenderer`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer) has to be initialized with the property `{alpha: true}`. The clear color and alpha channel have to be set 0, but this is default:

e.g.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } ); 
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
```

See the example with a cube which is drawn over a background image:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, loader, camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -2);

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.setCrossOrigin("");

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;
    
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.5 );
    directionalLight.position.set(1,2,1.5);
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    
    addGridHelper();
    createModel();

  }

  function createModel() {

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#b090b0'});
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function addGridHelper() {
    
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);
  }

  function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```css
#image-abs { position : absolute; top : 0; left : 0; z-index: -1; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<img id="image-abs" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/background.jpg">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I want to use the HTML as a background, in three.js.

Comment: @Mick `THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } )`